# ASP.NET Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, sql-server-2012

The next error pops when I initialize the `SqlConnection` object:

`Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.`

I have tried to solve this issue for hours (Also tried any of the advices I could find on SO), but with no success.

This is my connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Users.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

`Users.mdf` is located in the `App_Data` folder.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, .NET is Ver 4.5, with SQL Server 2012.
This issue started after I formatted my main driver, and installed the software I mentioned above.

Thanks, Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a connection string for SQL Server Express edition.

Do you have express edition installed on Dev machine?

I faced the same issue and only workaround was to create a database named `Users` in non-express edition of SQL Server.

Assuming that you have non-express edition installed, you need to attach the existing `Users.mdf` to SQL server as a database.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic590254-360-1.aspx

Connection string:
Server=localhost;Database=NewDatabaseName;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: I'm not very familiar with database handling with .NET, can you please explain why does it match to the Express edition? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Updated my answer with few details.

Comment: I noticed that the current connection string I use is the same as the one that VS is constructing when using their Table designer tool. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Can you try changing connection string to, AttachDbFilename=c:\path\to\mydbfile.mdf. Use full name with database filename.

Comment: With the full path it slows the website (8 seconds to load a page), and on debug I see a lot of networking exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems here is string in web.config is not correct
According to your set up sql, the string will work if you set something similar like this

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Movies;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; --> sometime, it will be Data Source=.;
```

after that, you need config right to access FOlder App_Data
If u test on Window 7, right click folder. property
Security tab -> add user network Service with full right

Answer (score 0):

it's ok; use it in your  web.config file ; thank you;

```
<add name="any name" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=name;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\name.mdf;Integrated Security=true; User Instance=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```